# Nginx redirect according to parameters

Tags: parameters, nginx, http-redirect

I want to be able to do the following :

Go to site http://mynginxserver.com/site=www.stack.com?a=b

Nginx need to redirect me to the address is site =

Can it be possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, not sure if it would work, also not really sure if I need to escape the `=`

```
location ^~ /site\=(.*) {
  return 301 http://$1$is_args$query_string;
}
```